# export typescript type in svelte file

Tags: typescript, svelte, sapper

I want to export the type that I defined in one of my files and import it inside another file.

```
export type myNewType = {name: string};
```

linter show me bellow error when I add `export`:

`Modifiers cannot appear here.`

I can make it work by creating a new `ts` file and import the type from it. I just want to know if there is a way to define type inside `svelte` file or not.

**Update:**

I use the sapper template and it will run without error but `TS` functionality not work and show me errors in `vscode` when importing type and export type from svelte file.

Comment: I guess it's just an issue with the linter. When you run the TypeScript check does it work?

Comment: yep, it will run with no error. I use sapper but the importing type will also show me an error and autocomplete not working.

Comment: TypeScript support in svelte is really new so I guess it's just an issue with the linter that you are using (and not the TypeScript compiler used by svelte). Which linter are you using?

Comment: I didn't set any linter and I guess it's `sapper` default linter

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need export the type from a module-script, not the normal script. You also need to add the `lang="ts"` attribute on either the normal script or the module-script. This will work:

```html
<script context="module" lang="ts">
  export type myNewType = {name: string};
</script>

<script>
  export let aProp: string;
</script>

<p>some html</p>
```

In general, whenever you want to import something from another Svelte file which is not the component itself, you need to declare that export inside the module-script.

Comment: This works but doesn't support Svelte's native `export let data`: under different context it becomes unavailable, so I can't for example `export type MyDataType = data` , because it's comming from different script tag :(

Answer (score 7):

Just in case it helps anyone, I was having an issue importing my own type which I had declared in a .ts file, into another library file:

My type was declared as follows:

```
export type UserAuth = {
    name: string,
    email: string,
    token: ''
};
```

An in my /lib/auth.ts file, I was attempting to import it as follows:

```
import { UserAuth } from "../types/user.auth";
```

Which produced an error that the type has not been exported.

The following fixed the issue for me:

```
import type { UserAuth } from "../types/user.auth";
```